# Early Modern English Dictionary API

Tags: api, language

I am building a web application that allows users to transcribe, word by word, Early Modern English manuscripts.

I want to tell users when a word they transcribed may be a new spelling variant of that word.

For doing that I need to interrogate a database via an API call. The database would be a comprehensive list of spelling variations of all words in Early Modern English.

I've tried the [Oxford English Dictionary one](http://public.oed.com/subscriber-services/sru-service/) but it seems a bit unreliable (sometimes it takes 40+ sec to return just a few records).

Has anyone done this before? Does anyone know of any API that could help?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll find more people with expertise in NLP over on our sister site, [Linguistics.SE]. The EL&U regular I'm aware of who might be able to shed light on this topic is @tchrist, but I haven't seen him around in a while.

Comment: Depending on the usage that you envisage it might be worth taking a look at Vard, http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/vard/userguide/, as it seems to be doing much of the same thing.

Comment: @SteveBarnes thanks. I knew about Vard, but I thought it was a desktop based application. I need something I can access from the web. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That is what I meant about depending on usage - IIRC Vard is Java based so it should be possible, with the permission and cooperation of Alistair Baron and Lancaster University, to split out the back-end processing to run on something like an Amazon service __if your usage is academic__. Then you would benefit from what they have done and possibly Vard could get the logs from the service to expand the corpora. This would be win-win.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Usage will be academic. It's for a citizen science project. Wouldn't that be a lot of work for Alastair?

Comment: How much work it would be for Alastair depends a) on how the code is currently structured and b) how much of it you do with his agreement - it sounds like your usage would fit in with the licence terms.